# Unix Script to Process multiple file names

Tags: command-line, loops, command, unix

I'm writing a script that will fold, sort and count text in a file. I need to design the program so that, if it is given multiple filenames on the command line, it processes each one separately, one after the other. I think I could write a loop but I don't know that much about those yet so if possible would like to try other options. Are there other options that I can add to this so more than one file name can be entered in the command line?

if test $# -lt 1
then
  echo "usage: $0 Enter at least one DNA filename"
  exit
fi
if test -r $*
then
  fold -w3 $* | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2
else
  echo "usage: $* must be readable"
  exit
fi

Nena

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` loop will be appropriate here. The following form is used to iterate over positional arguments:

```
for f; do
   # do work here using "$f" as the current argument
done
```

This is equivalent to a more verbose version:

```
for f in "$@"; do
   # do work here using "$f" as the current argument
done
```

Comment: Thank you Roman, I need to learn more about the "for" loop. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop and `shift` to iterate through the command line arguments one by one as:

```
if test $# -lt 1  # insufficient arguments.
then
  echo "usage: $0 Enter at least one DNA filename"
  exit
fi

# loop through the argument on by one.
# till their number($#) becomes 0.
while test $# -gt 0  
do    
if test -r "$1"  # use $1..$* represent all arguments.
then
  fold -w3 "$1" | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2
else
  echo "usage: $1 must be readable"
  exit
fi

# shift so that 2nd argument now comes in $1.
shift

done
```

Comment: That's a horribly complicated way, and it's missing double quotes around `$1` throughout. @user475364: just go with [Roman Cheplyaka's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930403/unix-script-to-process-multiple-file-names/3930534#3930534).